# Get Groups using Ldap in java

Tags: java, ldap

How can i get a particular user groups using Active Directory ?
I am getting all groups but i want to get groups which user is belonging

```
  public static String ldapUri = "ldap://pdc.example.com:389";
  public static String usersContainer = "cn=users,dc=example,dc=com";  
  public ArrayList<String> getUserGroups(String email, String password){
    ArrayList<String> list = new   ArrayList<String>();
       Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUri);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, email);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    try {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
        String[] attrIDs = { "cn" };
        ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
        ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);

        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(usersContainer, "     (objectclass=group)", ctls);
        while (answer.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult) answer.next();
        Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();
        String groups = attrs.get("cn").toString();
        String [] groupname = groups.split(":");
        String userGroup = groupname[1];
        System.out.println(attrs.get("cn"));
        }
        ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am getting all groups of a user by using this

```
String[] attrIDs = {"cn"};
ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
String[] attributes = {"memberOf"};
ctls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);
NamingEnumeration<?> answer = ctx.search(usersContainer, "(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=userName))", ctls);
```

Comment: Will this get all the groups from another trusted domain in same forest as well ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Active Directory.
User has the attribute 'memberOf'; fire a search query for specific user and include 'memberOf' in return attributes.

```
String[] attrIDs = { "cn", "memberOf" };
ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);

NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(usersContainer, "(&(objectclass=person)(cn=*sahi*))", ctls);
```

'memberOf' attribute holds the groups which the user belongs to.

Comment: Yes. I accept. After changes i am getting group name.